# How to clone a has_many association

Tags: ruby, clone

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

Foo oldFoo = Foo.new

Foo foo = Foo.new
foo.bars << oldFoo.bars.all.collect { |bar| bar.clone }
```

The above command doesn't replace the bars.foo_id properly, the references of oldFoo.bars gets removed and get set to foo.bars.

How should I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.bars << oldFoo.bars.all.collect { |bar| Bar.new(bar.attributes) }
```

Protected attribute assignment will throw an error in R3.2 though.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like it's the same thing as `clone`, so it's not much better. If you define methods like (I use them a lot):

```
class Hash
 def select_at(*s_keys)
    Hash[s_keys.zip(values_at(*s_keys))]
  end

  def reject_at(*r_keys)
    select_at(keys - r_keys)
  end
end
```

you can write `Bar.new(bar.attributes.reject_at("id", "foo_id"))`.